# Web Interface for a server application

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, tcp

I'm building a server-client application that uses TCP/IP sockets to communicate and i want to build a web interface to manage things.

Technologies:
-TCP/IP Sockets;
-Entity Framework 6 Code First;

My solution consists of four projects:
1) Server (Console application, runs 24/7, recieves data and writes to the db);
2) Client (Console application, runs 24/7 sends data);
3) NetLib (Class Library);
4) Interface (WebForms, entered occasionally, shows data from the db);

As for reading and managing data I'm good because all of them are written to the DB by Server and read by the Interface. But I have an issue: I want to be able to execute actions from the interface such as "Send new config to the client". How should i approach this? Creating a new socket in the interface project and sending it to the client sounds really bad.
Desired solution would be that the Interface somehow "tells" the server to perform such action. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

When your client sends data to the server, have your server send a response (if you are not doing this already). The response can contain any commands that the client needs to perform (such as update client configuration).

Now, your WebForms program needs to inform the server of whatever actions it needs clients to perform. This can be done in many ways, depending on how your system is set up.

- The WebForms program can write to the database and have the server read from it.

or

- The server can listen on a socket and the WebForms program would connect to this socket. If the WebForms program does not know where the server is, the server could write its address (DNS name/IP address) to the database, and the WebForms program would retrieve this address from DB and connect.

or some other way that suits you